# Make a symfony 1.4 task run as a daemon

Tags: linux, symfony-1.4, daemon

I have a symfony task already setup. The symfony task basically instantiates an object of a class whose __construct() method calls another method of the same class in an infinite loop. Now I would like this task to run infinitely as a daemon on my ubuntu server. I've tried running the task with nohup and using the & at the end to run it in background. But I noticed that the process is killed after about 8-9 hours or so and this is not what I want. So I figured having it run as a proper daemon that starts up with the system and can also restart itself if it gets killed for one reason or the other would be the right way to go. So I need help on how to go about this. Basically for those who don't know what a symfony task looks like, an example is this: symfony namespace:sometask.

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man1/daemon.1.html should help you start, this program can "daemonize" any, or almost any process

Comment: As far as I'm concerned PHP is not a very good at daemonizing itself. (You can get some strange behaviour after hours of runtime) If you need a function to be run repeatedly I would go for a cronjob.

Comment: @MichalTrojanowski cron jobs won't suffice here because the process needs to keep running indefinitely as opposed to every X minutes/hours

Comment: You can run the cron process every minute and assure your code runs for one minute. If you really need it to run as a deamon I wouldn't use PHP as it will cause many problems.

Comment: I understand your point but it has to be PHP since that's what i'm using to develop. Basically its not like i want to create the daemon directly using PHP. Instead the symfony framework allows you to create tasks that can be run from the CLI. These tasks however execute a bunch of PHP code. So all i want is for the command that runs this task to run as a daemon.